# CS0246 помогите плиз

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Помогите исправить ошибку. вот как она выглядит и скрин и код и текст ошибки.Незнаю как исправить помогите буду благодарен!

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnityStandartAssets' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка гласит что библиотека под названием `UnityStandartAssets` не существует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно написали название библиотеки (правильно UnityStandardAssets).

Если это не решит проблему, то попробуйте удалить и заново импортировать Standard Assets из Unity Asset Store
(https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-for-unity-2017-3-32351)

Answer (score 0):

Правильно так: `UnityStandardAssets`. Если что-то связано в скрипте с этим, то измени на название, которое я показал.

Comment: чем ваш ответ отличается от ответа, даного 17 авг '20 в 15:14 (кроме того, что короче)?